# Design your own connection to MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, lisp, connection

I am interested in creating my own connection to MySQL or PostgreSQL in Common Lisp. I know there are a few libraries that already exist for Common Lisp, but I want to have a better understanding of the respective database languages and Common Lisp by doing so myself. I searched around google and stackoverflow a bit, but did not find anything related to what I am looking for. I looked around the MySQL and PostgreSQL documentation as well, but did not find anything either. Perhaps I am not sure what I need to be looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the language in which clients and servers communicate is called a protocol. Search "mysql protocol" or "postgres protocol" for the specification you need to implement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html

http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/protocol.html